# Linux package management with Python

Tags: python, linux, package-managers

I am a **complete** Python beginner and try to write a **Python script** to automate the setup of a SDK on **Linux** machines from remote *Github* repositories.

The script starts by performing some basic preliminary operations, especially the *check/setup* of several packages (`git`, `docker`, `pip`, etc.).

For now, I target Debian (*Stretch, Buster*), Centos (6, 7) and Ubuntu Server 18.04LTS.
Of course, I want the script to run on the **widest range** of linux machines.

Today I rely on available *package managers* (`apt-get` and `yum`), roughly requested through `subprocess.call()` statements.

I customize the related commands using *nasty* script configuration variables like below :

```py
    import platform

    distribution                    = platform.dist()[0]
    version                         = platform.dist()[1]

    if      distribution == 'debian':
            pkgInstaller            = 'dpkg'
            pkmManager              = 'apt-get'
            checkIfInstalled        = '-s'
            installPackage          = 'install'
            yesToAll                = '-y'
            dockerPackage           = 'docker-ce'
    elif    distribution == 'centos':
            pkgInstaller            = 'rpm'
            pkgManager              = 'yum'
            checkIfInstalled        = '-q'
            installPackage          = 'install'
            yesToAll                = '-y'
            dockerPackage           = 'docker'
```

I then simply loop on an *array* containing the *names* of packages to be installed, then run the command through `subprocess.call()` :

```py
    prerequisites                   = ['git', dockerPackage, 'doxygen', 'python2-pip']

    for pkg in prerequisites:
        pgkInstallation = subprocess.call(['sudo', pkgManager, yesToAll, installPackage, pkg])
```

While this approach may have the benefit of not having *too much* bonding to *third-party* Python modules, **I guess there are... some smarter ways of doing such simple operation ?**

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is doing `subprocess.call(['sudo', pkgManager, yesToAll, installPackage, *prerequisites])` to install all at once.

Comment: There are mature configuration management tools written in Python for the purpose, like Ansible, Puppet, Chef, ...

Answer (score 1):

Usually when doing switch statements like this, a dictionary might be a bit more useful. Also, normally I'm not one to try to PEP-8 things, but this is an instance where PEP-8 might really help your readability by not matching up your equals signs for all of your lines of code.

The `dict` will hold your `distro` as the key, and your vars as a value wrapped in a tuple

```py
options = {
    'debian': ('dpkg', 'apt-get', '-s', 'install', '-y', 'docker-ce'),
    'centos': ('rpm', 'yum', '-q', 'install', '-y', 'docker'),
    }

# unpack this function call here
distribution, version, *_ = platform.dist() 


# now get the match
pkg_installer, pkg_manager, check, install_pkg, yes_to_all, docker = options[distribution]

requisites = ['git', docker, 'doxygen', 'python2-pip']

for pkg in requisites:
    pgkInstallation = subprocess.call(['sudo', pkg_manager, yes_to_all, install_pkg, pkg])
```

The `options[distribution]` call will raise a `KeyError` for unsupported distributions, so you can probably catch that and raise something a bit more useful like:

```py
try:
    pkg_installer, pkg_manager, check, install_pkg, yes_to_all, docker = options[distribution]
except KeyError as e:
    raise ValueError(f"Got unsupported OS, expected one of {', '.join(options.keys())}") from e
```

To make it less verbose, the only var you use out of order is `docker`, so you can house all of the others in a single var:

```py
try:
    *args, docker = options[distribution]
except KeyError as e:
    raise ValueError(f"Got unsupported OS, expected one of {', '.join(options.keys())}") from e

requisites = ['git', docker, 'doxygen', 'python2-pip']

for pkg in requisites:
    pgkInstallation = subprocess.call(['sudo', *args, pkg])
```